# Delete node from clob if namespace exists in oracle 12c

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a xml like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns4:EligibilityRequest xmlns:ns5="http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/eligresponse" xmlns:ns1="http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/mmiscommon" xmlns:ns4="http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/eligrequest" xmlns:ns3="http://xmlns.eohhs.ma.gov/newMMIS/ws/2006/05/MemberInfo">
                <ns4:transactionsource id_medicaid="100027128782" id_other="00001740934" id_source="HIX"/>
                <ns4:demographic dte_birth="1986-10-24" cde_sex="F" num_primary_ssn="031725754" cde_citizen="C" cde_race="UNKNOW" cde_ethnicity="UNKNOW" cde_homeless="N" cde_primary_lang="ENG" cde_lang_written="ENG" num_phone_day="4135376954" email="slpaullrn@gmail.com" nam_last="Paull" nam_first="Stephanie" nam_mid_init="L" res_adr_street_1="173 Abbott street" res_adr_city="Springfield" res_adr_state="MA" res_adr_zip_code="01118" mail_adr_street_1="173 Abbott street" mail_adr_city="Springfield" mail_adr_state="MA" mail_adr_zip_code="01118" amt_indv_prem="0" amt_indv_income="0.00" amt_income_fpl="3293.34" pct_income_fpl="166.19" ind_pregnancy=" " cde_tpl_status="S" cde_born_to_st_empl=" "/>
                <ns4:case num_case="00938195C" cde_case_status="1" hoh_nam_first="Stephanie" hoh_nam_last="Paull" hoh_nam_init="L" amt_family_prem="0" amt_family_mh_prem="12.00" amt_family_prem_assist="0"/>
                <ns4:eligibility dte_begin_elig="2015-10-12" dte_end_elig="2016-09-06" cde_line="00" cde_elig_status="4" cde_cat="40" amt_gross_income="2470" family_size="4" dte_appl="2015-10-22" cde_region="58" cde_office="555" cde_close_reason="M1"/>
                <ns4:eligibility dte_begin_elig="2016-08-13" cde_line="00" cde_elig_status="1" cde_cat="AP" amt_gross_income="3293.34" family_size="4" dte_appl="2015-10-22" cde_region="58" cde_office="555" cde_open_reason="01"/>
                <ns4:uncompdeductible amt_uncmp_deductible="993" dte_effective="2016-08-13"/>
</ns4:EligibilityRequest>;
```

There is 2 tag of `<ns4:eligibility`. I want to delete one tag where we have cde_close_reason exists. Please advise

Comment: Please specify where and why oracle, sql, plsql, and plsqldeveloper are related to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work..

```
SQL> with MY_TABLE as
  2  (
  3    select XMLTYPE(
  4  '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  5  <ns4:EligibilityRequest xmlns:ns5="http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/eligresponse" xmlns:ns1="http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/mmiscommon" xmlns:ns4="http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/eligrequest" xmlns:ns3="http://xmlns.eohhs.ma.gov/newMMIS/ws/2006/05/MemberInfo">
  6                  <ns4:transactionsource id_medicaid="100027128782" id_other="00001740934" id_source="HIX"/>
  7                  <ns4:demographic dte_birth="1986-10-24" cde_sex="F" num_primary_ssn="031725754" cde_citizen="C" cde_race="UNKNOW" cde_ethnicity="UNKNOW" cde_homeless="N" cde_primary_lang="ENG" cde_lang_written="ENG" num_phone_day="4135376954" email="slpaullrn@gmail.com" nam_last="Paull" nam_first="Stephanie" nam_mid_init="L" res_adr_street_1="173 Abbott street" res_adr_city="Springfield" res_adr_state="MA" res_adr_zip_code="01118" mail_adr_street_1="173 Abbott street" mail_adr_city="Springfield" mail_adr_state="MA" mail_adr_zip_code="01118" amt_indv_prem="0" amt_indv_income="0.00" amt_income_fpl="3293.34" pct_income_fpl="166.19" ind_pregnancy=" " cde_tpl_status="S" cde_born_to_st_empl=" "/>
  8                  <ns4:case num_case="00938195C" cde_case_status="1" hoh_nam_first="Stephanie" hoh_nam_last="Paull" hoh_nam_init="L" amt_family_prem="0" amt_family_mh_prem="12.00" amt_family_prem_assist="0"/>
  9                  <ns4:eligibility dte_begin_elig="2015-10-12" dte_end_elig="2016-09-06" cde_line="00" cde_elig_status="4" cde_cat="40" amt_gross_income="2470" family_size="4" dte_appl="2015-10-22" cde_region="58" cde_office="555" cde_close_reason="M1"/>
 10                  <ns4:eligibility dte_begin_elig="2016-08-13" cde_line="00" cde_elig_status="1" cde_cat="AP" amt_gross_income="3293.34" family_size="4" dte_appl="2015-10-22" cde_region="58" cde_office="555" cde_open_reason="01"/>
 11                  <ns4:uncompdeductible amt_uncmp_deductible="993" dte_effective="2016-08-13"/>
 12  </ns4:EligibilityRequest>') as XMLDOC
 13      from dual
 14  )
 15  select XMLQUERY(
 16          'declare namespace ns = "http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/eligrequest"; (: :)
 17           copy $NEWXML := $XML
 18           modify(
 19             delete nodes $NEWXML/ns:EligibilityRequest/ns:eligibility[@cde_close_reason]
 20           )
 21           return $NEWXML'
 22           passing XMLDOC as "XML"
 23           returning content
 24         ) RESULT
 25    from MY_TABLE
 26  /

RESULT
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1252" standalone='yes'?>
<ns4:EligibilityRequest xmlns:ns5="http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/eligresponse" xmlns:ns1="http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/mmiscommon" xmlns:ns4="http://newmmis.eohhs.ma.gov/serviceobjects/versions/1.0/eligrequest" xmlns:ns3="http://xmlns.eohhs.ma.gov/newMMIS/ws/2006/05/MemberInfo">
  <ns4:transactionsource id_medicaid="100027128782" id_other="00001740934" id_source="HIX"/>
  <ns4:demographic dte_birth="1986-10-24" cde_sex="F" num_primary_ssn="031725754" cde_citizen="C" cde_race="UNKNOW" cde_ethnicity="UNKNOW" cde_homeless="N" cde_primary_lang="ENG" cde_lang_written="ENG" num_phone_day="4135376954" email="slpaullrn@gmail.com" nam_last="Paull" nam_first="Stephanie" nam_mid_init="L" res_adr_street_1="173 Abbott street" res_adr_city="Springfield" res_adr_state="MA" res_adr_zip_code="01118" mail_adr_street_1="173 Abbott street" mail_adr_city="Springfield" mail_adr_state="MA" mail_adr_zip_code="01118" amt_indv_prem="0" amt_indv_income="0.00" amt_income_fpl="3293.34" pct_income_fpl="166.19" ind_pregnancy=" " cde_tpl_status="S" cde_born_to_st_empl=" "/>
  <ns4:case num_case="00938195C" cde_case_status="1" hoh_nam_first="Stephanie" hoh_nam_last="Paull" hoh_nam_init="L" amt_family_prem="0" amt_family_mh_prem="12.00" amt_family_prem_assist="0"/>
  <ns4:eligibility dte_begin_elig="2016-08-13" cde_line="00" cde_elig_status="1" cde_cat="AP" amt_gross_income="3293.34" family_size="4" dte_appl="2015-10-22" cde_region="58" cde_office="555" cde_open_reason="01"/>
  <ns4:uncompdeductible amt_uncmp_deductible="993" dte_effective="2016-08-13"/>
</ns4:EligibilityRequest>


SQL>
```